# compiling source code on 2 different versions of gcc

Tags: c, gcc

I am compiling my source code on 2 different machines that use different versions of gcc.

cflags c89

```
-Wall -Wextra -Wunreachable-code -g -m32 -D_DEBUG -O0 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_REETRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE
```

One is redhat-4

```
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)
Linux 203_test_server 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:51:48 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And one is Fedora 18

```
gcc (GCC) 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8)
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.8.1-201.fc18.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Feb 28 19:23:08 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My fedora 18 compiles with no errors. However, on the redhat 4 machine I get some errors.

```
channel.h:35: error: redefinition of typedef ‘channel_t’
internal.h:19: error: previous declaration of ‘channel_t’ was here
```

I think the error is just a circular problem. However, with the same code base would compiling on 2 different machines really make a difference using 2 different versions of gcc?

I was thinking using a newer version of a compiler will generate more errors, as the newer compiler might be more strict.

**This is not a question to solve the error, but a general question on compilers.**

Is there any flags I can set to avoid this in the future. Maybe if compiling on this version of gcc do this, if the versions are not compatible?

Comment: Yes, different compilers/versions/flags might produce different results, esp. in `#ifdef`-heavy code.

Comment: as far as `any flags I can set to avoid this in the future`, does my answer cover that, or were you thinking of something different?

Comment: some useful info would be nice, its more likely to be an included header different on one system than the compiler, but you never mention where channel.h or internal.h are or how they get included.  the surrounding lines around where channel_t appears would be useful too ... at least to the ifdefs.  Your CFLAG defines mean absolutely nothing without that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a duplicate of: [Why "Redefinition of typedef" error with GCC 4.3 but not GCC 4.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526322/why-redefinition-of-typedef-error-with-gcc-4-3-but-not-gcc-4-6)

The answer is that gcc was changed to modify this check.

http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commitdiff;h=ce3765bf44e49ef0568a1ad4a0b7f807591d6412

Sometimes, warnings for behavior defined in the language, but considered bad practice, are considered too strict because certain useful and/or harmless use cases are included in the warning. Compiler developers then try to fix in the opposite way, that is, reducing the amount of warnings. In this case, the change made the warning appear only when the second definition changed the typedef to a different, but compatible type.

Other current example is -Wshadow in gcc 4.8 just announced. In the release note, it says that -Wshadow won't warn anymore if a function name is shadowed by another.

See:
http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html

Edit: how you can avoid this: either delete one of the definitions, or move it to a separate  include file and delete both other definitions.

Answer (score 10):

It would depend on what headers are being included by the source code. If you're linking to external libraries, it may be that your source code is incompatible with the version of a library installed on the older system.

If the source code doesn't include any external library headers (except the C library) then there may be preprocessor directives that need changing.

EDIT:

After a [Google](http://www.google.com) search, it appears that `channel_t` is from a kernel header. You're using kernel releases far apart on the two machines. If the code depends on a kernel header file, it may well require a kernel version newer than on the Red Hat machine. You haven't specified what the code is (is it a device driver?), or what files it's including, so it's difficult to say more.

Answer (score 4):

Compare the contents of channel.h and internal.h on the two systems where you are getting different results.  I doubt the issue is the version of gcc.  It's more likely that the errors are a result of code changes to those files over time, like when one system has a newer version of a library and the associated header files than the other.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, let’s talk about your problem a little. I think the most likely cause of your system giving errors on one system over the other is the code isn’t identical; you might want to verify this via some tool or `diff` command to look for any subtle changes that have come up in your code base. 
Normally when I’ve seen problems with that error type, you have something like:

```
typedef struct Foo* Fooptr;
```

In a header file and then:

```
typedef struct Foo
{
    int bar;
} *Fooptr;
```

in the source file. Which means you can just drop the typedef in the source and it should be OK. Just something to look for.

Now if it *is* a `gcc` issue, a second option to solve your problem is, it’s possible to [have multiple versions of gcc on the same computer](http://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#multiple) and then to specify the exact version of `gcc` to run with via the `-v` option. So it might be a good idea to give 4.1.2 a shot on your Fedora 18 machine.

Another note, if you use the `-v` option, but *do not* specify a version of `gcc` to run, you’ll get (on the stderr output) the commands executed to run the stages of compilation. This could be useful to see what’s going on and if there are any major differences between what’s happening on each machine.

---

OK, now on to your questions. Yes, there are flags for compiling on “version X” of `gcc`:
For starters there is the [`__VERSION__` Predefined Macro](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html), this will spit back to you a `const char *` of the version number. This can be quite useful, but as the gcc documentation states:

> You should not rely on its contents having any particular form, but it can be counted on to contain at least the release number

Despite that, I’ve typically seen only 1 form of output from this which is something like `"4.6.3"` if my version of `gcc` is `4.6.3-1ubuntu5`.

Now if you know (or suspect) that some of your code will cause a particular version of `gcc` to cause errors you can use the `__GNUC__`, `__GNUC_MINOR__`, and `__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__` predefined macros to "protect" yourself:
Here’s a short snip-it showing at the highest level how to use it:

```
#if __GNC__ == 3
    printf(“Hello version 3.x.x\n”);
#elif __GNC__ == 4
    printf(“Hello version 4.x.x\n”);
#endif
```

So on the above system where the version is 4.6.3 you’d see the “Hello version 4.x.x” message. Then you can get more advanced and check the subversions as well:

```
#if __GNUC__ > 3 || \
    (__GNUC__ == 3 && (__GNUC_MINOR__ > 2 || \
        (__GNUC_MINOR__ == 2 && \
          __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__ > 0))
    printf(“I’m a gcc greater than 3.2.0\n”);
#endif
```

Or the cleaner version of that using your own macro:

```
#define GCC_VERSION (__GNUC__ * 10000 \
    + __GNUC_MINOR__ * 100 \
    + __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__)
#if GCC_VERSION > 30200
    printf(“I’m a gcc greater than 3.2.0\n”);
#endif
```

---

To address your question about if different versions of `gcc` will produce different errors, you are correct that in each release of `gcc` there is more going on and sometimes things do change so you’ll see differences between different versions of the compiler. The best bet is to check the release notes for each version between the two you’re on. (from 4.1 to 4.7).

- 4.2 - http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.2/changes.html
- 4.3 - http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html
- 4.4 - http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/changes.html
- 4.5 - http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html
- 4.6 - http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html
- 4.7 - http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html

I’m not sure what target architecture you have, so make sure that you check those specific sections in each of the documents. But I think you really want to have a look at the `"Build system improvements"` and the `"Incompatible changes to the build system"`, they also make a section specific to C code which could be handy to review.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information here to say precisely what's going on.  I join with those who say it's unlikely to be a compiler version problem.

This error occurs (obviously) when the compiler encounters two different declarations for the same name.  It should not be too hard to figure out why this is happening.

Check the makefile to find the `internal.h` and `channel.h` header files that are being referenced. The cited lines will have a `typedef` or other declaraion for `channel_t` there.  Work outward from these declarations for clues.

I must assume that one or both of these files are in libraries you are using.  If both `internal.h` and `channel.h` are your own code, debug your own code!

Otherwise there are many possibilities. The most likely are

1. Preprocessor `-D` or `#define`ed flags are not correct so that multiple declarations are being conditionally compiled when only one should be.
2. Two different libraries or else standard headers and a library have a name clash.
3. Your own code has a clash with a library or standard header. If `channel_t` is a type you defined, that's a problem. You should not define your own types ending in `_t` because these are reserved for the implementation.

Number 1 above can occur in several ways, but the most common is misconfiguration of a library. Libraries must usually be `./configure`ed for the OS they're being used on. If you configure in one Linux and copy to another, you are asking for problems like the one you are seeing.

Number 2 could occur on one linux and not the other due to library version differences.  In this case, update the machine with the error to the same versions as the one without the error. Don't forget to run `./configure`.

For Number 3 the fix is obvious.  Change your type name.

I see a `channel.h` and `channel_t` in Tor.  My wild guess is that you're using Tor and looking at a Tor misconfiguration on the machine with the error.

Answer (score 1):

> This is not a question to solve the error, but a general question on
>   compilers.
>
> Is there any flags I can set to avoid this in the future.

Each specific version of a compiler will come with its own switches or flags.

If the compiler version was created to accept certain switches and one of those is the one you need to avoid certain checks on your source code then yes there is/would be a way to avoid it in the future.

If the compiler version, recent or future version, you are using does not have/accept a switch to avoid/skip certain checks on your source code then there's no way to avoid it.