# Can I port RetroArch to Native Client

Tags: c++, google-chrome, open-source, google-nativeclient

So I've been cutting my teeth on another coding project, and figured that the best thing that I could try is to port RetroArch all in one Emulator into Native Client, so that it could very well be a packaged app with cloud saves entirely within a browser. Look up the project on Github since I don't have enough links.

The way RetroArch is built on linux is to run a configure script, then make, then sudo make install. Altering the configure agent to select the Native Client compilers, I was able to get a couple seconds into the build when this happened,

http://pastebin.com/0WtrY6aU

using this custom Makefile here.

http://pastebin.com/iv6RmQVr

I figure it's gonna be a long hard road building and debugging this puppy, but where do you recommend I get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're starting from a good place, you've just hit your first compile error.

Here it is:

```
In file included from settings.c:23:
input/input_common.h:73: error: redefinition of typedef ‘rarch_joypad_driver_t’
driver.h:327: note: previous declaration of ‘rarch_joypad_driver_t’ was here
```

Here is an excerpt from input_common.h:

```
typedef struct rarch_joypad_driver
{
   ...
} rarch_joypad_driver_t;
```

Here is an excerpt from driver.h:

```
typedef struct rarch_joypad_driver rarch_joypad_driver_t;
```

Just as the error says, the typedef is being redefined. I ran a test using gcc 4.6.3 from Ubuntu 12.04:

```
typedef struct foo { int bar; } foo_t;
typedef struct foo foo_t;
int main() { return 0; }
```

This compiles and links fine. The same code compiled with x86_64-nacl-gcc (which is using gcc 4.4.3), gives the following error:

```
typedef.c:2: error: redefinition of typedef ‘foo_t’
typedef.c:1: note: previous declaration of ‘foo_t’ was here
```

It seems that this error has been relaxed in more recent versions of gcc. I did some searching and found this stackoverflow link: [Why "Redefinition of typedef" error with GCC 4.3 but not GCC 4.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526322/why-redefinition-of-typedef-error-with-gcc-4-3-but-not-gcc-4-6).

It's worth noting that x86_64-nacl-g++ will compile this code unmodified. Here are two things to try:

1. Compile with CC using x86_64-nacl-g++ instead of x86_64-nacl-gcc
2. ## ifdef out the definition in driver.h, and replace the other use in that file with `struct rarch_joypad_driver`.

For #2, you can use the following:

```
#ifndef __native_client__
...
#endif
```

Good luck, there likely will be more compile failures to fix. :)

Comment: Thank you. I take it is not common procedure to PM or continue a thread with every compile error I get, so should I try to figure this stuff out on my own, or ask for help every time I hit a wall?

Comment: I'm happy to help, though maybe SO is not the best place. Maybe try #nacl on irc.freenode.net, or the native-client-discuss Google Group?